# dotencode property through mercurial-server issue

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-server

Just want to notice: this issue is **only** about sharing mercurial using mercurial-server

Steps to reproduce:

1. create new repository with `hg init`
2. try to clone it through mercurial-server:

   ```
   hg clone ssh://hg@192.168.132.72/test2 .
   remote: abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!
   прервано: no suitable response from remote hg!
   ```
3. edit `.hg/requires` file, remove `dotencode` property
4. repeat step 2:

   ```
   hg clone ssh://hg@192.168.132.72/test2 .
   изменений не найдено
   updating to branch default
   0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
   ```

Any ideas why it is happening and how I could fix it?

ps: it is mercurial 1.9 installed, and the command is performed from the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened because:

1. I had mercurial site-packages installed in both `/usr` (new, from 1.9) and `/usr/local` (old, from 1.6). And `hg-ssh` had taken the old ones.
2. `hg-ssh` needs to be patched a little

   ```
   dispatch.dispatch(['init', repo])
   ```

   should be replaced with

   ```
   dispatch.dispatch(dispatch.request(['init', repo]))
   ```

   and

   ```
   dispatch.dispatch(['-R', repo, 'serve', '--stdio'])
   ```

   with

   ```
   dispatch.dispatch(dispatch.request(['-R', repo, 'serve', '--stdio']))
   ```

   accordingly

Comment: @Idan K: `hg-ssh` in mercurial-server is a huge file, not equal to the original one

Answer (score 1):

The most recent release of mercurial-server, version 1.2, fixes this problem.

Comment: I hope it does *now* ;-) But there was no 1.2 that time

Comment: 1.2 only came out a few days ago. No criticism was intended, I assure you, I just wanted to make sure this page had the most recent information!  In case it's not clear, I'm the author of mercurial-server.

Comment: yep, I know you are. And I emailed you personally with this issue and its solution, but you didn't reply me :-(